# implementing login check using spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am currently self educating myself with spring mvc by working on a small database project but i am stuck on inital step of login validation.

```
package Spittles.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper;

import Spittles.services.LoginService;
import SpringForm1.model.Spittler;

public class SpittlerDao implements LoginService {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.dataSource=dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public Spittler checkSpittlerLogin(Spittler spittlerLogin)
    {
        String sql="SELECT * FROM spittler where spittler_email=? and spittler_password=?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,new ParameterizedRowMapper<Spittler>(){
                public Spittler mapRow(ResultSet rs,int rowNum)  throws SQLException
                {
                    Spittler spittler = new Spittler();
                    spittler.setSpittler_name(rs.getString("spittler_name"));
                    spittler.setSpittler_email(rs.getString("spittler_email"));
                    spittler.setSpittler_email(rs.getString("spittler_id"));
                    return spittler;
                }
        },spittlerLogin.getSpittler_email(),spittlerLogin.getSpittler_password() );
    }


}
```

and my LoginController is as follows.

```
package SpringForm1.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import Spittles.dao.SpittlerDao;
import Spittles.services.LoginService;
import SpringForm1.model.Spittler;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public String loginPage(@ModelAttribute("loginData")Spittler spittler)
    {
        return "login";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/logindo.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logindo(@ModelAttribute("loginData")Spittler spittler)
    {
        Spittler spittlerData = loginService.checkSpittlerLogin(spittler);
        if(spittlerData!=null)
        {
            return "home";
        }
        else
        {
            return "login";
        }

    }
}
```

Now then problem i am facing is that incase when use enters correct email and password i get redirected to home page which is as desired.But in case when either email or password is incorrect, my requirement is to be redirected back to login page but i get following exception.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

so what may be the problem? I am new to spring so any suggestion will teach me something 
new.

Answer (score 1):

you should first check the row number . result set will be empty in case of invalid login . so you have to first check whether the resultset is empty , then throw appropriate exception .

Answer (score 0):

May this can help ..

you don't need email and password back .So , modify the query to `Select count(*) from` ....
It will return you `1` or `0` always . handle your conditions based on that.

If you want implement standard in your project then implement spring security with custom authentication manager.